# TypeError: Object of type Tensor is not JSON serializable - dict to json error in Pytorch

Tags: python, json, pytorch, tensor

In my pytorch code, I have the below output of dictionary with losses:

```
errors = {0: tensor(64.4072, device='cuda:0'), 1: tensor(58.2704, device='cuda:0')}
```

I am converting this dict to a json and writing the json to a file with the below code:

```
json_object = json.dumps(errors, indent = 4)
    with open("train_loss_dic.json", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(json_object)
```

However, I am getting the below error:

```
TypeError: Object of type Tensor is not JSON serializable
```

How to convert Tensor so it is json serializable in Pytorch?
My versions are torch==1.9.0 and torchvision==0.10.0

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it need to be a tensor?  Why can't you convert it to just a `float` instead?  These are two tensors that are just scalar values.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have 1-element tensors, you can simply call `item()` on the tensors to recover a Python `float` from them. These are serializable.

You can use:

```
json_errors = {k: v.item() for k, v in errors.items()}
```

To get a new `dict` that is serializable.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: error = {}
total_error = total_validation_loss/len(ValidationImgLoader)
error[epoch] =total_error .item()

Will this append json serializable object to dictionary?

Comment: Yes, you can also do that. This works so long the tensor has only 1 element. I believe that in your case, it always will.